# Remove double values from array classic asp

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic, comparison

If i had an array such as -

```
array(0) = 85
array(1) = 85
array(2) = 53
array(3) = 203
array(4) = 85
```

How can I make a new array with no double values? so the array would be

```
array(0) = 85
array(1) = 53
array(2) = 203
```

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old question but recently I came across same scenario where i need to remove redundant entires from array. I searched SO but not found any simple method to do same.After searching  i got simple method on [Hey, Scripting Guy! Blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/).

From [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2006/10/27/how-can-i-delete-duplicate-items-from-an-array.aspx) link

```
Set objDictionary = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

arrItems = Array("a","b","b","c","c","c","d","e","e","e")

For Each strItem in arrItems
  If Not objDictionary.Exists(strItem) Then
      objDictionary.Add strItem, strItem   
  End If
Next

intItems = objDictionary.Count - 1

ReDim arrItems(intItems)

i = 0

 For Each strKey in objDictionary.Keys
   arrItems(i) = strKey
   i = i + 1
 Next

For Each strItem in arrItems
   Wscript.Echo strItem
 Next
```

Hope this will help some one

Comment: This is the only solution that I found that works... after replacing the Wscript.Echo with Response.Write.

Answer (score 1):

Using the function from [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590223/compare-values-of-two-arrays-classic-asp/6592801#6592801) with test code like

```
  Dim aA   : aA   = Split( "85 459 459 90 85 85 85" )
  Dim aRes : aRes = diffArray( aA, Array() )
  WScript.Echo "A  :", Join( aA )
  WScript.Echo "UNI:", Join( aRes( 0 ) ), "settifieds"
```

gives you:

```
A  : 85 459 459 90 85 85 85
UNI: 85 459 90 settifieds
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a function in vbs to remove duplicate element from array.If it not exists your can use the following.May be problem with the syntax but you can use the strategy

```
length=5
    newLength=1
    for i=0 to length-1

      for j=0 to newLength-1
      if(array(i)=array(j)) then
    exit For
    end if
      next
      if(j=newLength) then
    array(newLenth++)=array(i);
    end if

    next
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in n log n if you sort the array.

Comment: Can you show and example please or a link to something that shows an example where I can learn how to do that?

Comment: If you sort the array still you have to remove the duplicate and have to use the method below.So thinking about sorting is not good idea here,I think

Comment: +1 for pointing out that sorting is not needed for dups removal.