# How to get unique values from a list of values using VBscript?

Tags: vbscript

Suppose an Excel sheet has a column named *Student Names* and the column has duplicate values. Say,

```
Student
=======

Arup
John
Mike
John
Lisa
Arup
```

Using VBScript, how can I get unique values as below?

```
Arup
John
Lisa
Mike
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The VBScript tool for getting unique items is a dictionary: add all the items as keys to a dictionary and dictionary.Keys() will return an array of the - per definitionem - unique keys. In code:

```
  Dim aStudents : aStudents = Array("Arup", "John", "Mike", "John", "Lisa", "Arup")
  WScript.Echo Join(aStudents)
  Dim aUniqStudents : aUniqStudents = uniqFE(aStudents)
  WScript.Echo Join(aUniqStudents)

' returns an array of the unique items in for-each-able collection fex
Function uniqFE(fex)
  Dim dicTemp : Set dicTemp = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
  Dim xItem
  For Each xItem In fex
      dicTemp(xItem) = 0
  Next
  uniqFE = dicTemp.Keys()
End Function
```

output:

```
Arup John Mike John Lisa Arup
Arup John Mike Lisa
```

Comment: Hello Horner, Is there any Direct function or way in VBscript which can give how many rows of any specific columns filled with data?

Comment: @user1878162 - please post a new question.

Comment: please help me in my below post - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13823912/to-move-the-cell-values-in-a-group-from-right-to-left-if-any-group-of-cells-are

Comment: Does Dic.Keys() will automatically remove the duplicates? So Can you tell me what is the difference between Dic.Keys and Dic.Keys()?

Comment: @VBSlover: please study the Docs for Dictionary to learn (1) you can't put duplicate keys in a dictionary, so there is no removing at all; (2) the .Keys method is a method that returns something (an array of the dictionary's keys), the statement "x = d.Keys()" calls this method as a Function and assigns the return value, so according to the rule "use param list () when calling a function" the () should be there, *but* Mr. Gates' own sample code omits the () and still works, *so* decide for yourself whether you want to be pedantic (like me) or not.

Comment: Yes. I 100% agree with you.But now my question is `For Each xItem In fex
      dicTemp(xItem) = 0
Next` this part how removes the duplicates.Just a guess does it remove the duplicate keys at their entry time? correct me please If i am wrong.

Comment: @VBSlover: Straight from the Docs: "If key is not found when changing an item, a new key is created with the specified newitem." To spell the implication out: If the key exists, newitem is just assigned.

Comment: Yes,I understood that,if a Key say 9 is already added with an item, and a second attempt with the same Key (here 9) will not allow to add one more 9,rather it will update the `item` which 9 was previously holding. Nice concept. I am now 100% sure in this concept. Thanks @Ekkehard :-)

Comment: @ParthAkbari If http://stackoverflow.com/a/6592801/603855 doesn't help, post a new question (with some more details).

Comment: This is VERY helpful but it doesn't seem to be working for numerical values. I have an array "511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511, 511) and I want to reduce it down to the unique value "511" but the uniqFE function isn't working. Any thoughts?

Comment: @nbardach: If you replace the array of names by "Array(511, 511, 511)" you'll see that the function works as promised. Otherwise replace "not working" by a detailed description of inputs, outputs and errors.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since your source data is in an Excel spreadsheet, you could use SQL to fill an ADODB Recordset:

```
Option Explicit

Dim filePath, sheetName
filePath = "C:\path\to\excel\workbook.xlsx"
sheetName = "Sheet1"

Dim connectionString
connectionString = _
    "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
    "Data Source=""" & filePath & """;" & _
    "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=No"""

Dim sql
sql = "SELECT DISTINCT Student FROM [" & sheetName & "$]"

Dim rs
Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
rs.Open sql, connectionString

Do Until rs.EOF
    WScript.Echo rs("StudentName")
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want a Dictionary you can use the following to compare each element in the array to itself.

```
Info = Array("Arup","John","Mike","John","Lisa","Arup")

x = 0
z = ubound(Info)
Do
x = x + 1
Do
z = z - 1
If x = z Then
Info(x) = Info(z)
ElseIf Info(x) = Info(z) Then
Info(x) = ""
End If
Loop Until z=0
z = ubound(Info)
Loop Until x = ubound(Info)
For each x in Info 
If x <> "" Then
Unique = Unique & Chr(13) & x
End If
Next

MsgBox Unique
```