# Error: Object Required: 'example'

Tags: vba, vbscript

Hey I have this do until loop that takes a text file made into a string ("strnotapprovedData") and then calls this function that runs a command to delete the share. I keep getting the error object required: "xxxx". How do I fix this is the problem the function the loop statement or the string.

Function:

```
Function DeleteThisShare(Value)

   DeleteThisShare = "net share " & Share & " \DELETE"
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
    Msgbox AddQuotes(DeleteThisShare)
    objShell.Run DeleteThisShare

End Function
```

Loop Statement:

```
Do Until strnotapprovedData.AtEndOfStream
Dim objShare : objShare = Split(strnotapprovedData,vbCrLf)
    notapprovedShares = objShare
    DeleteThisShare(notapprovedShares)

Loop
```

String:

```
Dim notapprovedList, notapprovedShares
Set notapprovedList = objFSo.OpenTextFile ("C:\Users\abro\Shares_Not_Approved.txt")
Dim strnotapprovedFile, strnotapprovedData
strnotapprovedFile = ("C:\Users\abro\Shares_Not_Approved.txt")
strnotapprovedData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strnotapprovedFile,ForReading).ReadAll
```

Reply to Chris Nielsen

Well I added this and the same problem still occurs

```
strnotapprovedData = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strnotapprovedFile,ForReading).ReadAll

Do Until objnotapprovedLines.AtEndOfStream
    objnotapprovedLines = Split(Trim(strnotapprovedData),vbCrLf)
    DeleteThisShare(objnotapprovedLines)

Loop
```

Comment: I already provided you with a [working solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19489784/1630171). Why are you falling back to your old (non-working) code? If your real question is "how do I disconnect a network drive?": simply use the [`RemoveNetworkDrive`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d16d7wbf%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) method instead of shelling out.

Comment: I did use your code in another section of my script, this is for taking the shares that were not in either list and run a command line that deletes the shares. "Net Share "Share Name" /DELETE" to be exact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strnotapprovedData` is set to a string as a result of the `ReadAll` method of the file system object.  Since it is a string and not a stream, it will not have an `AtEndOfStream` property.  Instead, you should split it on line breaks and loop over the resulting array.

---

Response to edit:

Your code does not show where `objnotapprovedLines` is being defined or initialized. From your usage, I presume it starts life as a stream, but I have no way to know that. However, on the first line after your `DO`, you overwrite it to be an array.  Arrays do not have an `AtEndOfStream` property, so that would certainly cause the error, even if nothing else has.

Here is some untested code to try:

```
' Define a new variable called "notApprovedLines"
' VBScript is loosely-typed, so this could be anything at this point.
Dim notApprovedLines

' Read the contents of the file into the "notApprovedLines" variable.
' This assumes that you have a variable named "strnotapprovedFile" that
' contains the path to the file, as your example code indicates.  At the
' end of this, the "notApprovedLines" variable contains the entire contents
' of the file as one giant string.
notApprovedLines = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strnotapprovedFile, ForReading).ReadAll

' Split the contents of the file into an array, so we can deal with one line at
' a time. After this, "notApprovedLines" will be an array of strings, with each
' entry representing one line of the original file.
notApprovedLines = Split(notApprovedLines, vbCrLf)

' Loop over those lines
Dim x, k, line

' This sets the upper boundary of the loop.
k = uBound(notApprovedLines)

' In VBScript, arrays start at zero.  The "x" is our counter variable. Its
' value will be incremented with each iteration of the loop, so we hit the
' entries one at a time.
For x = 0 To k

    ' Trim whitespace away from each line.  After this executes, the "line"
    ' variable will contain a single line from the file, as a string, without
    ' and leading or trailing whitespace.
    line = Trim(notApprovedLines(x))

    ' We don't want to process blank lines, if any exist.  This test lets us
    ' skip those.  Any line that contained only whitespace would also be
    ' skipped here, since it's length would be zero after trimming away the
    ' whitespace.
    If Len(line) > 0 Then

        ' This executes your function. I have not really proofed it very
        ' closely. Let's hope it works! =)
        DeleteThisShare(line)

    End If
Next
```

Comment: Responded to script in original question.

Comment: @user2890980 - I have updated my answer with some code to try.

Comment: Thanks your loop works great but the logic in my function is were the real problem is. I used your loop but the command "net share "line" /DELETE" still doesn't run. Could you help me with that