# Remove multiple elements in dynamic array in Classic ASP

Tags: arrays, vbscript, asp-classic

I'm trying to iterate through a dynamic array and remove elements if the date has been exceeded. The array has been generated from a comma separated string.

My code is as follows:

```
Sub delete(ByRef ar, ByVal idx)
    Dim i
    Dim ub

    ub = UBound(ar) - 1

    For i = idx To ub
        ar(i) = ar(i + 1)
    Next

    ReDim Preserve ar(ub)

End Sub


    Dim invitation,invitation_array
    invitation = rs("visningID")
    invitation_array=split(invitation,",")

    invitationStr = "Select * From visningTable Where Id=" & invitation_array(v) & ""
    Set rsInvitation = Conn.Execute(invitationStr)


For v=LBound(invitation_array) to UBound(invitation_array)

  If CDate(rsInvitation("Dato")) < Date then

    Dim ar
    Dim i

    ar = invitation_array

    delete ar, v  '' pass the name of the array, and the index of the element to delete

  end if
```

I can't get it to remove the correct elements and in the end the array is completely messed up?
Where do I go wrong?

Comment: Well I guess I know what goes wrong. As the code iterates the changing index numbers of the array messes everything up.

Comment: Why not using SQL only to get what you need? `strSQL = "Select Id From visningTable Where Id In (" & invitation_array & ") And Dato>=GetDate()"` will return only records which are both in the array and have date bigger than the current date. Isn't this what you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The best tool for de-duplicating an array is the Dictionary:

```
>> a = Array( 1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 1 )
>> Set d = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
>> For Each e In a : d(e) = 0 : Next
>> b = d.Keys()
>> WScript.Echo Join(b), TypeName(b), TypeName(b(0)), b(0)
>>
1 2 3 Variant() Integer 1
```

([See also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6590223/compare-values-of-two-arrays-classic-asp/6592801#6592801))

If you want to **replace** a with the unique elements, just assign `a = b`.